# SQL Query - Aggregate Sends/Opens/Clicks and group by Data Extension Attribute?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to build a SQL query that will show count of distinct sends/clicks/opens grouping by an attribute in the associated data extension.  I'm struggling to find the join criteria between data extension & `_sent` / `_click` / `_Open` tables.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to counts of a recent send. You can join on the `JobId` on [_Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5), [_Click](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5), and [_Open](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5) data views. The `JobId` can be found in the Tracking of recent sends. You can also join on `SubscriberKey`, but not all records will exist in Open or Click data views.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT SubscriberKey) AS Number_Of_Records
FROM _Sent s
INNER JOIN _Open o ON s.JobId = o.JobId
INNER JOIN _Click c ON o.JobID = c.JobId
WHERE s.JobId = '12345'
```

Comment: Thanks - the JobID could be helpful here (however I'm not seeing it in my data extension).  How can I join from my data extension to the 'tracking of recent sends'?  As for SubscriberKey, that won't help as the same subscriber would exist in multiple data extensions.

Comment: Are you sending to the same sendable data extension across multiple sends? You can grab the JobId from Email Studio > Email > Tracking > Sends. And then build a where clause of all the JobIds where you use that sendable data extension.